# Selenium login with memorable word

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a few selenium scripts that login with a username and password but now the login has had a memorable word added.

So the login now goes,  username, password and then the memorable word prompt will ask for letters 3 5 6 from your memorable word or maybe 1 3 4,  it changes each time.

Does anybody have an idea of how to add this to a selenium script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35289242/954442

Comment: yes, show me your html source and i will help you with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for now what you need to do is to save the word.

```
string word = "something";
```

after that in every place that the website asking you for example char 3
from your word you take this number.

```
int charIndex = Int32.TryParse(driver ...); // search for the number
```

word.Substring(charIndex - 1, 1); // this is the value to the textbox